# create append set inner html and give the element a class in one line?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to do this with vanilla javascript and I don't understand why this does not work especially in a loop.

What I am trying to do is create a paragraph element, append it to the document, give it a class, and insert some text as inner html all in one line without setting any of the parts to a variable. Is this possible?

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('p')).className = "test".innerHTML = "some text";
```

This line of code will take what is in the innerHTML and set it as the class name for the element. Why does this happen? I am so confused.

Comment: Any special reason why you would like to use one line? Because it's harder to read than just creating a method that returns an element and call that method.

Comment: Because this is the only time the program creates these elements. They are also created using a loop where the loop goes through an array and gives each element their class and innerHTML text.

Comment: Still no reason of making the code hard to read. Always try to program as if someone else should read the code. I mean, the way you write the code is probably a reason why it's not working, because you can't see what you've been doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
document.body.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('p'),{classList:"test", innerHTML:"some text"}));
```